# Functional Guards in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards, angular-guards

I want to prevent navigation by changing the URL and only navigate on button click.
My code:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivateFn, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class CanActivateGuard {
  private allowNavigation = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  setAllowNavigation(allow: boolean) {
    this.allowNavigation = allow;
  }

  canActivate: CanActivateFn = (): boolean => {
    if (this.allowNavigation) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['']); // Redirect to a safe route if not allowed
      return false;
    }
  };
}
```

Is this correct for functional guard in angular? I'm still writing a class, so I think I'm doing something wrong here. The setAllowNavigation is called from clicking a button.

I was expecting to have only one function where I can pass a parameter to allow navigation or not and this parameter would be a default parameter to false.

Answer (score 0):

When defining a fonctionnal guard like `CanActivateFn` you should be having only a function:

For example :

```
const canActivateTeam: CanActivateFn =
    (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
      return inject(PermissionsService).canActivate(inject(UserToken), route.params.id);
    };
```

This example is for the [official doc](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateFn).

If you need to injection something in that function you should rely on [`inject`](https://angular.io/api/core/inject)